Why is totalResults.Count returning 0 on my powershell code
I am trying to get every file that matches the filename, in console it works but on $totalResults, it's empty. This is the console log:
Found file: payment1_200.txt
Found file: payment_200.txt
Matching file: payment1_200.txt with Pay ID: 200
Matching file: payment_200.txt with Pay ID: 200
Total matching results: 0
This is the code:
    $payIDRange = $textBoxPayID.Text
    $payIDParts = $payIDRange -split "-"
    $payIDStart = [int]$payIDParts[0]
    $payIDEnd = [int]$payIDParts[1]

    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Files\$region"
    
    foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
        Write-Host "Found file: $($file.Name)"
    }

    $totalResults = @($allFiles | Where-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match "payment.*_(\d+)\.txt(\.txt)?$") {
            $filePayID = [int]$matches[1]
            Write-Host "Matching file: $($_.Name) with Pay ID: $filePayID"
            return ($filePayID -ge $payIDStart -and $filePayID -le $payIDEnd)
        }
        return $false
    })
    
    Write-Host "Total matching results: $($totalResults.Count)"

I tried changing the code multiple times but nothing seems to work.

it's not missing, it's upper on code:
$payIDParts = $payIDRange -split "-"
$payIDStart = [int]$payIDParts[0]
$payIDEnd = [int]$payIDParts[1]

i made the change on post

and $payIDRange what value does it have?

added that too now

So this is part of an event handler from some form. Have you tried Write-Host $payIDStart, $payIDEnd in that handler to ensure those values are correctly populated with the values you expected?

yes they are correct i mean the if logic executes and it logs everything, in this case it logs: 200 0

if it is literally $payIDStart = 200 and $payIDEnd = 0 then your -ge and -le comparisons are reversed.
